# Make List of Algorithms formatting match LOT/LOF

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms, algorithmic

I'm working on my thesis, and I have a minor formatting problem with my list of algorithms.
The entry is added properly in the TOC and the font, size dotting and numbering are perfect, but for some reason, the LOA is about a centimeter lower than the LOF/LOT from the top of the page.

Here's my MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true, listformat=simple]{subcaption}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\newpage
\singlespacing
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{7em}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\updatechaptername{%
   \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand*\protect\cftchappresnum{\@chapapp\ }}
}
\makeatother
\tableofcontents
\updatechaptername

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Algorithms}
\listofalgorithms

\doublespacing

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chap:intro}

\newpage
\chapter{Content}
\label{chap:content}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that the package `float` command `\listof` (which is loaded by package `algorithms`) does not format the same way as package `tocloft`. The following (untested with real algorithms) should work. It is a copy-paste of the `\listoffigures` `tocloft` command, suitably modified. (see also the section Known issues of the `algorithms` documentation)

[your mwe was lacking a `\begin{document}`, I cuoldn't to mention it in a comment as I don't earn enough reputation points]

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true, listformat=simple]{subcaption}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{%
\@cfttocstart \par \begingroup 
\parindent\z@ \parskip\cftparskip 
\addpenalty \@secpenalty 
\if@cfthaschapter \vspace*{\cftbeforeloftitleskip } \else 
                  \vspace {\cftbeforeloftitleskip } \fi
\@cftpagestyle 
{\interlinepenalty \@M 
  {\cftloftitlefont \listalgorithmname }%
  {\cftafterloftitle } 
\@mkboth {\MakeUppercase \listalgorithmname }
         {\MakeUppercase \listalgorithmname }
\par \nobreak \vskip \cftafterloftitleskip \@afterheading }%
\let\l@algorithm\l@figure
\@starttoc {loa}\endgroup 
\@cfttocfinish }}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\newpage
\singlespacing
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{7em}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\updatechaptername{%
   \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand*\protect\cftchappresnum{\@chapapp\ }}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\updatechaptername

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables


\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Algorithms}
\listofalgorithms

\doublespacing

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chap:intro}

\newpage
\chapter{Content}
\label{chap:content}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was at a conference out of the country.  I'll try this immediately and accept as soon as I got it working, thanks ! (Also, I fixed my MWE according to your comment.)

Comment: For those that stumble across this answer and are using `algorithm2e` instead, you can replace `\listalgorithmname` with `\listalgorithmcfname` to get a similar result.

Comment: For `algorithm2e`, you also need `\let\l@algocf\l@figure` -- `algocf` is the label used in the `.loa` file. Also, `\listalgorithmcfname` will not contain anything unless using `dotocloa` in the `algorithm2e` options. Or you can simply define it as `\def\listalgorithmcfname{List of Algorithms}` for a quick solution